# Сумма платежей за определенный период по дням

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! В бд хранится информация о платежах(дата платежа и сумма).

```
2016-03-24 : 18900.00
2016-03-24 : 7560.00
2016-03-28 : 0.00
2016-06-21 : 0.00
2016-08-03 : 1899.00
2016-08-18 : 230.00
2016-08-26 : 150.00
2016-08-26 : 160.00
```

Нужно посчитать сумму платежей за каждый день, т.е в итоге должно быть так:

```
2016-03-24 : 26450.00
2016-03-28 : 0.00
2016-06-21 : 0.00
2016-08-03 : 1899.00
2016-08-18 : 230.00
2016-08-26 : 310.00
```

Как это можно сделать, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Просуммировать с группировкой по  дню `SELECT SUM(summa), date, FROM table GROUP BY date`

Comment: @Ivan Bolnikh, А как можно переделать мой запрос? `"SELECT sum, datetime FROM payments  WHERE datetime between '$before' and '$after'"`

Comment: @r.mcreal ну так добавь в запрос `GROUP BY date` и `SUM(summa) as summa`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, Примерно так: `SELECT SUM(summa) as summa, datetime FROM payments GROUP BY datetime WHERE datetime  between '$before' and '$after'` ?

Comment: @r.mcreal у тебя колонка `datetime` тип какой? дата + время или только дата как описано в вопросе, просто названа так?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, точнее дата в формате гггг-мм-дд

Comment: @r.mcreal  если формат с минутами часами и секундами, то тогда надо приводить к формату без них.... иначе группировка не сработает: `SELECT SUM(summa) AS summa, DATE(\`datetime\`) AS \`datetime\`
FROM payments
WHERE \`datetime\` BETWEEN '$before' AND '$after'
GROUP BY  DATE(\`datetime\`)` .... ну и не забыть в самом php использовать подготовленные запросы вместо вставки переменных напрямую

Comment: @r.mcreal `точнее дата в формате гггг-мм-дд` - так какой **точно** тип столбцов даты? date? datetime? timestamp? формат...

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, Спасибо большое! Только теперь выдает такую ошибку `#1054 - Unknown column 'summa' in 'field list' `. Мне поле 'summa' самому создать в таблице или как?

Comment: @r.mcreal потому что никто кроме тебя не знает как называется колонка с суммами у тебя в таблице - ты не предоставил такие сведения и писали от балды... там должно быть имя столбца как у тебя в таблице

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, Вот пример даты `1458816701`

Comment: @r.mcreal разве это не int?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, все запрос сработал. Спасибо! Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу теперь получить данные?

Comment: значит группировку надо делать по `from_unixtime(\`datetime\`, '%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score -1):

```
$sum_day = null;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT sum FROM payment_table WHERE day=:day');
$stmt->execute(array('day' => $day));
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $sum_day .= $sum_day + $row['sum'];
}
echo $sum_day;
```

Comment: А как можно переделать мой запрос? `"SELECT sum, datetime FROM payments  WHERE datetime between '$before' and '$after'"`

Comment: смотрите. я здесь использую пдо так как оно более безопасно. а ваш запрос будет выглядеть примерно так... `$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT sum, datetime FROM payments WHERE datetime between :before and :after');
$stmt->execute(array('after' => $after, 'befoere' => $before));`